# input on focus out / blur background position?

Tags: javascript, css, onblur, onfocus

I have a inputfield with class. On focus the bg image position gets changed.
But I need to set back to the position after on focus out.

any way to do this? probably with some js?

the css

```
.login-day{width: 68px; height:48px; line-height: 48px; background: url(/assets/templates/img/dd.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat transparent;}

.login-day:focus{background-position: -68px 0;}

.login-day:focus-out???{background-position: 0 0;}
```

the html

```
<input class="login-day" type="text" name="date" />
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/9Q6nN/1/

---

**Solved:**
http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/9Q6nN/4/

Answer (score 2):

To reset position again to previous one use Hover instead of focus. Try this

```
.login-day{width: 68px; height:48px; line-height: 48px; background: url(/assets/templates/img/dd.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat transparent;background-position: 0 0;}

.login-day:hover{background-position: -68px 0;}
```

By jquery also it is possible

```
<input class="login-day" type="text" name="date" onfocus="$('.login-day').css('background-position','-68px 0px');" onblur="$('.login-day').css('background-position','0px 0px');" >
```

Comment: thanks, but that isn't what i'm looking for. I have seen some js scripts to use blur/focus out but i dunno how to implement.

Comment: than use javascript for these, place two functions on input field, check updated answer

Comment: jup but need some help with that :(

Comment: is the answer i have updated above is not what you are looking for

Comment: i have check this please use this <input class="login-day" type="text" name="date" onfocus="$('.login-day').css('background-position','-68px 0px');" onblur="$('.login-day').css('background-position','0px 0px');" >

Comment: thanks Raju, it works. I noticed on blur needs to be bg position 0 0 too. the best would be when its still empty then background position 0-68px 0; but i don't this its an easy task.

Comment: never mind- i think its ok like this.. i will update my fiddle